# Single input field with formula then calculate that formula onblur, returning result to same field with jQuery or JS

Tags: jquery, calculated-field

I would like to input a formula in an input field, then onblur the formula I just typed will calculate and return the result in the same field, replacing the formula.

ex. inputing 2+2 gets replaced with 4 onblur or inputing (8*4)+3 gets replaced with 35.

I'd like to use the class to bind the script so I can use it on multiple fields. Is there a command or function I need to call to tell jquery that I want to calculate the contents of the single input?  I found 50 answers about calculating multiple input boxes, but not 1 answer about using just a single input field for everything.

UPDATE: I've revised my jQuery to work with eval, though that is considered super dangerous and I can't actually use it.  But seeing it work at least was optimistic.

I also deleted the link to my fiddle because as was pointed out, jsfiddle isn't loading any jquery libraries so it will never work on there.

```
<html>
<input id='formula_and_total' class='self_calculate'>
</html>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input.self_calculate').on('blur', function() {
    //let formula = $ (input, this).val ();
    let formula = $(this).val();
    //let formula = document.getElementById ('formula_and_total').value;
    $(this).val(eval(formula));
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this solution. (if i got you right)

```
<input id="formula_and_total" class="self_calculate">
```

Use a well formated input tag -> with "" to prevent errors.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".self_calculate").on("blur", function () {
                let formula = +$(this).val() + 1;  // add 1
                $("#formula_and_total").val(formula);
            });
  });
```

My demo formula just add's 1 to the input field.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on " vs '.  And I see you defined the input using the id instead of "this".  But the 1 you are adding is coming from hard code or another input.  I want the formula to be entirely within the same input as the returned calculation. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of problems with the provided code. first, your jsfiddle is not using jquery, so $ will be undefined.

next, the selector `$("input[.self_calculate]")` will not find the input you are trying to get. instead you would use something like `$("input.self_calculate")`.

next, the `text()` method does not get/set text in an input field, instead it would be used to set the text nested within a tag, so like `<p></p>` would become `<p>formula</p>` using `text('formula')` on it. instead for inputs you would want to use the `val()` method to get/set an input's value.

next, `$(this).attr("value")` is always going to equate to an empty value. either use `prop('value')` or `val()` to get the input's current value.

next, i am not sure what you are trying to do with the `+` before `$(this).attr("value")`. this will do nothing as far as I can tell.

next, even after switching the last line to something that would set the value of the input, you are setting the value to a literal string by putting quotes around 'formula'. if you want to set it to the value of the variable named formula, you would remove the quotes, so it would look like this: `$(this).val(formula);`

next, nothing in your code will help javascript calculate a formula. you would have to do something like run `eval()` on the input's value to calculate a mathematical formula, but that would leave your site open to security holes and is not recommended. here it is anyways for learning purposes, but please don't post this on a public facing site as it will run any javascript code typed into the input: `$(this).val(eval(formula));`

Comment: That helped a lot.  Thank you for pointing out where my code was a mess.  It was just a combination of the scripts I'd seen for using multiple inputs, so I was not surprised I was way off.  So it works now with eval, but is there a safe alternative to eval? Or a safe way to use it?

Comment: @FunctionalHippie the safe way would be to have a huge block of code that knows how to parse the text into its various symbols with regex and apply the right operations to the right parts of the text, but I have a feeling that is a bit more than you will be wanting to bite off right now considering the complexities possible in a mathematical formula. instead you may want to start with something a bit simpler and google a tutorial on how to make a calculator with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your time and experience @dqhendricks.